# What would be your representation of a particule as an angular directive

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs-directive, angular-directive, angular2-directives

I believe, the answers will provide nice and complete examples of angular's directives and also different points of view of actual understanding about particules. It applies to Angularjs and Angular too! So, Many best answers possible based on theories and also I think, funny challenge that leads to great learning material

Can have several properties: volume, density, or mass. Electron, atoms and molecules, to macroscopic particles like powders and other granular materials. Particles can also be used to create scientific models of even larger objects depending on their density.

Thank you!

Comment: What's a particule?